# Mod_Rewrite with multiple PHP variables and dynamic text

Tags: php, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

So here's the deal:

`episode.php?s=1&e=3` brings up information for season 1 episode 3.

So make it SEO friendly I want to be able to have users be able go to the following:

`domain.com/episodes/ShowName_Season_1_Episode_3_The_Title_Of_The_Episode.html` (or without the .html, doesn't really matter).

This is what I have so far:

```
RewriteRule ^episodes/([a-z0-9-]+)_$_([a-z0-9-]+)_$_([a-z0-9-]+).html episode.php?s=$1&e=$2
```

I know this is not right...how can I make it take the two numbers in the rewritten URL and associate them with PHP GET variables in the actual URL?

I know how to do more basic mod_rewrites but this one has been confusing me. I am guessing it is something stupid, so thanks in advance for your patience.

Answer (score 3):

Here's what you can do:

```
RewriteEngine ON

#domain.com/episodes/ShowName_Season_1_Episode_3_The_Title_Of_The_Episode.html
RewriteRule ^episodes/([a-z0-9\-]+)_Season_([0-9]+)_Episode_([0-9]+)_(.*)$ episode.php?s=$2&e=$3 [NC,L]

#Even more SEO friendly: http://domain.com/ShowName/Season/3/episode/4/title/
RewriteRule ^episodes/([a-z0-9\-]+)/season/([0-9]+)/episode/([0-9]+)/(.*)/? episode.php?s=$2&e=$3 [NC,L]

#or Even more SEO friendly: http://domain.com/episodes/ShowName/season-3/episode-1/title
RewriteRule ^episodes/([a-z0-9\-]+)/season\-([0-9]+)/episode\-([0-9]+)/(.*)/? episode.php?s=$2&e=$3 [NC,L]
```

I don't recommend to use "_" for SEO but "-"

Comment: For some reason when I use the last line that you said would be best for SEO, I lose all style info and my images no longer appear.

It goes to the correct PHP page, but none of the styling is there. Pretty much all text.

EDIT: it is now trying to find my images and css stuff ehre: episodes/dexter/season-3/episode-2/css/img/icons/diglog24.png

instead of /cdd/img/icons/diglog24.png where it's supposed to be.

Comment: to show the images css, js, etc. you have to put the [`base`](http://www.htmldog.com/reference/htmltags/base/) tag in your html

Comment: tttony is right. Make sure in your HTML code you use the base tag or you reference all your CSS, JS or Images with / eg: <img src="/css/img/icons/diglog24.png"> that way you will see the image correctly.